# NUnit best practice

Tags: tdd, nunit

*Environment: (C# WinForms application in Visual Studio Professional 2008)*

I've been digging around a little for guidance on NUnit best practices. As a solo programmer working in a relatively isolated environment I'm hoping that collective wisdom here can help me.

Scott White has a few good starting points [here](http://scottwhite.blogspot.com/2008/05/nunit-best-practices.html) but I'm not sure I totally agree with everything he's said -- particularly point 2. My instincts tell me that the closer a test is to the code being tested the more likely you are to get complete test coverage. In the comments to Scott's blog posting is a remark that just testing the public interface is considered best practice by some, but I would argue the test framework is not a typical class consumer.

What can you recommend as best practices for NUnit?

Answer (score 6):

If by point 2, you mean the "bin folder per solution" -- I can see your point.  Personally, I would simply add the reference to each test project.  If, on the other hand, you really mean (1b) "don't put your tests in the same assembly as your code" I heartily agree with him and disagree with you.  Your tests should be distinct from your production code in order to enhance code clarity and organization.  Keeping your test classes separate helps the next programmer understand it more easily.  If you need access to internals in your tests -- and you might since internal methods are "public" to the assembly, you can use the InternalsVisibleTo construct in the Assembly.cs file.

I, too, would recommend that, in general, it is sufficient to unit test only the public interface of the code.  Done properly (using TDD), the private methods of your code will simply be refactorings of previous public code and will have sufficient test coverage through the public methods.  Of course, this is a guideline not a law so there will be times that you might want to test a private method.  In those instances, you can create an accessor and use reflection to invoke the private method.

Another recommendation that I would make is to use unit testing and code coverage in tandem.  Code coverage can be a useful heuristic to identify when you need more tests.  Lack of coverage should be used as a guide to indicate where more testing may be needed.  This isn't to say that you need 100% coverage -- some code may be simple enough not to warrant a unit test (automatic properties, for instance) and they may not be touched by your existing tests.

There were a couple of issues that I had with the article.  Probably the biggest is the lack of abstraction away from the database for unit tests.  There probably are some integration tests that need to go against the db -- perhaps when testing trigger or constraint functionality if you can't convince yourself of their correctness otherwise.  In general, though, I'm of the opinion that you should implement your data access as interfaces, then mock out the actual implementations in your unit tests so that there is no need to actually connect to the database.  I find that my tests run faster, and thus I run them more often when I do this.  Building up a "fake" database interface might take a little while but can be reused as long as you stick with the same design pattern for your data access.

Lastly, I would recommend using nUnit with [TestDriven.Net](http://testdriven.net/) - a very useful plugin whether you're doing nUnit or MSTest.  Makes it very handy to run or debug tests with a right-click context menu.

Answer (score 6):

> My instincts tell me that the closer a
>   test is to the code being tested the
>   more likely you are to get complete
>   test coverage. In the comments to
>   Scott's blog posting is a remark that
>   just testing the public interface is
>   considered best practice by some, but
>   I would argue the test framework is
>   not a typical class consumer.

If your code cannot be tested using only public entry points, then you have a design problem. You should read more about TDD and [SOLID principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) (especially single responsibility principle and dependency inversion). Then you will understand that following TDD approach will help you write more testable, flexible and maintainable code, without the need for using such "hacks" as testing classes' private parts.

I also highly recommend reading [Google's guide to testability by Miško Hevery](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/), it has plenty of code samples which cover these topics.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a fairly similar situation and this question describes what I do [keep-your-source-close-and-your-unit-tests-closer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653545/keep-your-source-close-and-your-unit-tests-closer). There weren't too many others enamoured with my approach but it works perfectly for me.